# Gopher Protocol Request

Tags: http

Would like help in understand the following line "gopher://:8080/_POST%20/x%20HTTP/1.0%0ACookie: eatme%0A%0AI+am+a+post+body", is it even possible to craft a post request using the gopher protocol that include parameters and values just like http?

Need help in solving a ctf question that is possibly related to this

Comment: Do you actually have a gopher server?  I haven't seen one in 25 years.  You can't send a gopher request to an HTTP server, and most of the modern browsers will not send a gopher request.

Comment: @TimRoberts gopher is alive an well! There's actually more servers every year, but they are counted as hundreds (maybe thousands now?) so very much a niche ;)

Answer (score 0):

Gopher and HTTP are alternatives of each other.

Gopher does not have a concept of a `POST` request, that's a HTTP term. Gopher allows for some limited interactivity but it's *mostly* a protocol for reading.

So you can think of it as HTTP, but only GET requests and no headers. The address you shared looks completely broken and not a valid gopher url. Perhaps the URL was crafted to find a security vulnerability and a gopher-to-http proxy but it's a complete guess.

Ultimately a gopher server will receive a 'path' from a client, and it's free to do *something* with that path, including using it to proxy to a different HTTP server. The line reminds me of what someone might to hack a server that's vulnerable to HTTP response splitting.

**edit** Just read this is for a capture-the-flag type thing, I think that confirms my theory. I won't help anymore beyond this though.